# Remove AD-user in domain A from AD-group in domain B while my client is in domain C in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, cross-domain

Let's assume I have an AD-user in domain A which is in an AD-Group in domain B and my client is in domain C.
I want to remove the user from the group in PowerShell, but I really can't figure out how I can solve this problem using `Remove-ADGroupMember` or `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` since I can only pass one domain there.

Comment: In theory it should work if you use the Distinguished Names of the objects. I can't test this atm but try it like this: `Get-ADgroup -Identity <DN of the group> | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members <DN of the user>`

Also take a look at the official documentation of `Remove-ADGroupMember`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know this, but my SamAccountNames and domains result from a database request and I wanted to avoid extra requests in order to find the DNs.

Comment: Well if you atleast have the DN of the Domains, you can try it with the `Partition` parameter:
`Get-ADGroup -Identity <SAM in B> -Partition <DN of B> | Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAM in A> -Partition <DN of A>`

Again, I couldn't try this but it looks like it could work :D

Comment: What about: `Get-ADGroup -Identity <SAM in B> -Server <domain B> | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members <SAM in A> -Server <domain C>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that domains A & B are not in the same forest, but are trusted.

The issue is that you're not removing a direct reference to the user: You're removing a Foreign Security Principal, which is an object on the same domain as the group that references the account in the trusted domain. I talk about this in a little more detail in an article I wrote: [What makes a member a member?](http://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html).

None of the PowerShell cmdlets seem to be able to handle these. But you can use .NET's `DirectoryEntry` class to do this. Here is an example (`$username` and `$groupname` are the names of the account and the group):

```
$u = Get-ADUser -Server domainA.com $username
#Get the Foreign Security Principal object for the user
$fsp = Get-ADObject -Server domainB.com -Filter "objectSid -eq '$($u.SID)'"

#Get the group
$g = Get-ADGroup -Server domainB.com $groupname

#Get a DirectoryEntry for the group (which is what the [ADSI] notation creates)
$group = [ADSI]"LDAP://domainB.com/$($g.DistinguishedName)"

#Remove the FSP from the group
$group.Properties["member"].Remove($fsp.DistinguishedName)
$group.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below cmdlet to remove foreign principal objects from groups

```
set-adgroup -remove @{member='cn=S1-5-blah-blah-blah'}
```

Steps:
get the DistinguishedName of foreign principal member

```
$mem = (get-ADGroup 'GroupName' -property members).members |where {$_ -like "CN=S-1-5-21-BLAHBLAH"}

set-ADGroup -remove @{member=$mem}
```

You can  also use `Set-ADgroup -clean member` to empty group membership including foreign principal objects.